# SQL returns only some of the results for a complex one to many query

Tags: sql, ms-access

My table structure is as follows

**Endoscopy**:

```
PK:Endoscopy_Id
FK:PatientId
```

This is many to one with...

**Patient**

```
PK:Patient_Id
```

This is one to many with `Endoscopy` and with `Histology`

**Histology**

```
PK:Histology_Id
FK:PatientId
```

This is one to many with

**HistologyDetails**

```
PK:HistologyDet_Id
FK:Histology_Id
```

I am trying to perform a query which will extract all the 'astroscopies' and some fields from histology and histologydetails for all the patients. At the moment I am not getting all the results and I am not sure why. I am using:

```
SELECT 
    Endoscopy.*, 
    Histology.Diagnosis, Histology.NatureOfSpec, 
    Histology.Histology, 
    HistolDetails.MeasurementLargest, HistolDeatils.NumberBx 
FROM 
    Endoscopy  
JOIN 
    PatientData ON Endoscopy.HospNum_Id = PatientData.HospNum_Id   
JOIN 
    Histology ON Histology.HospNum_Id = PatientData.HospNum_Id  
JOIN
    HistolDetails ON Histology.Histology_Id = HistolDetails.Histology_Id
WHERE 
    histology.VisitDate = endoscopy.VisitDate 
    AND (ERFINDINGSSTR LIKE '%Barret%'OR ERDIAGNOSISSTR LIKE '%Barret%') 
    AND Endoscopy.ERPROCEDUREPERFORMED LIKE '%astroscopy%'
```

Comment: since you are doing a regular join if there is no data in PatientData, Histology or Histoldetails then the row will not return , thats the nature of that type of join.  Try switching them to left outer joins and see if you get the data you expect and go from there

Comment: Good question Sebastian - you've presented your question well and showed your code, indicating some effort.  Not sure why it was marked down. Are you using Query Wizard - or trying the Query View to get what you want? Right click on the Join line to set Properties of it - from there you can change the left/right conditions as per @TheRk suggestion

Comment: OK. Thanks. I have used a left join and seems to be working now. Need to mug up on my joins I suppose. @TheRK put as an answer?

Comment: Added as an Answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you only use Join it will only return your Dataset if correlating rows exists in those tables, PatientData, Histology and Histoldetails.

You will want to use Left Joins if the data in the joined tables may or may not have a relationship.

FYI just using Join like you have correlates to an Inner join in the below image

[image]